# Where do I download Java development binaries (JDK) for Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, download, java, jdk

I am trying to install a Java development environment on Windows 7 64-bit, but I am unable to find a suitable install. Is there one available?

Comment: Then depending on the SDK you have, for instance mine is: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\java.exe`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The latest Java Development Kit is available at [this address](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp). Make sure to select "Windows x64" when asked for the operating system.

[image]

Comment: Just a heads up, this is out of date now that update 17 is released.

Comment: I've tried to keep on top of updating answers but I really haven't got the time any more. I leave it up to people to look at the date the answer was posted and put 2 and 2 together.

Comment: Due to the high views on this question please update this link if you have a moment.

Comment: Appears you can get 64 bit JRE (just JRE) there as well. Thanks!

Comment: Re image: The next to last line, Windows X86 (79.48MB), is that the Windows 32 bit version? 
x86 = 32 bit
x64 = 64 bit.
Is that a fair assessment?

Comment: @zundarz Yes – that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

[Java SE Downloads page](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp)

Choose the appropriate JDK package you want and select Windows x64 on the subsequent page.