# Download link for JDK & jre 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, download, jdk, jre

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 64-bit and Java JDK download](https://superuser.com/questions/30312/windows-7-64-bit-and-java-jdk-download)

I want to do download jdk 64bit (last update) for Windows and Linux but I can`t download it from oracle.com

It says Forbidden

Who can give me a true link for download jdk and jre 64 bit!

Comment: i say it . i can NOT download it from ***oracle***

Comment: Well, [this](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u26-b03/jdk-6u26-windows-x64.exe) is the link for the x64 JDK, and [this](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u26-b03/jre-6u26-windows-x64.exe) is the link for the JRE. Both work here.

Comment: please give me a link **except** oracle.com and sun.com , please

Comment: Why don't they work? Are you behind a firewall that blocks oracle.com or are you having any other strange network issues?

Comment: NO! I`m in IRAN and **oracle** and **sun** blocked iranian to download thare products.

Comment: Why didn't you say that first? Did any of the answers below work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Sun-Java-JRE-Download-34334.html) and [Filecluster](http://www.filecluster.com/downloads/Sun-Java-JRE.html) offer downloads of both the JRE and the JDK, but personally, i would prefer the original source. At least you should check the md5 checksum.

Answer (score 0):

[jdk6.java.net download source](http://jdk6.java.net/download.html)

> Java™ Platform, Standard Edition 6u27 Binary Snapshot Releases.